# How to know Solr Search Works in Magento CE

Tags: php, mysql, magento, solr, lucene

I'm working with Solr Search integration on Magento CE 1.7.0.2 from fast couple of days..

At finally i solved all errors in that.

Right now i have one small doubt whether the solr search is working or not in my local Magento.Because it looks same as default magento - MySQL search, I don't get Spelling correction, & I'm getting Suggestions but looks like default search.

Here I'm posting my solr logs.. Please take look at that give me conformation.

**This is my solr logs when i starts the server...**

```
1    [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server  – jetty-8.1.10.v20130312
28   [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider  – Deployment monitor /root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/contexts at interval 0
36   [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager  – Deployable added: /root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/contexts/solr-jetty-context.xml
1154 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor  – NO JSP Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
1192 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – SolrDispatchFilter.init()
1209 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – JNDI not configured for solr (NoInitialContextEx)
1210 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – solr home defaulted to 'solr/' (could not find system property or JNDI)
1210 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – new SolrResourceLoader for directory: 'solr/'
1347 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolr  – Loading container configuration from /root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/solr.xml
1458 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolrXml  – Config-defined core root directory: 
1467 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – New CoreContainer 22711257
1467 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – Loading cores into CoreContainer [instanceDir=solr/]
1481 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting socketTimeout to: 0
1481 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting urlScheme to: http://
1482 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting connTimeout to: 0
1482 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting maxConnectionsPerHost to: 20
1483 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting corePoolSize to: 0
1483 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting maximumPoolSize to: 2147483647
1484 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting maxThreadIdleTime to: 5
1484 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting sizeOfQueue to: -1
1484 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory  – Setting fairnessPolicy to: false
1588 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher  – SLF4J impl is org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory
1589 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.logging.LogWatcher  – Registering Log Listener [Log4j (org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory)]
1616 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  – Looking for core definitions underneath /root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr
1630 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  – Found core collection1 in /root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/
1631 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  – Found 1 core definitions
1632 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – Creating SolrCore 'collection1' using instanceDir: /root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1
1632 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – new SolrResourceLoader for directory: '/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/'
1703 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig  – Adding specified lib dirs to ClassLoader
1705 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar' to classloader
1706 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar' to classloader
1706 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/metadata-extractor-2.6.2.jar' to classloader
1706 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar' to classloader
1706 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar' to classloader
1706 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/isoparser-1.0-RC-1.jar' to classloader
1707 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar' to classloader
1707 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar' to classloader
1707 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/tagsoup-1.2.1.jar' to classloader
1707 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar' to classloader
1707 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/tika-core-1.4.jar' to classloader
1707 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/pdfbox-1.8.1.jar' to classloader
1708 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar' to classloader
1708 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/poi-3.9.jar' to classloader
1708 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/vorbis-java-tika-0.1.jar' to classloader
1708 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar' to classloader
1708 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/netcdf-4.2-min.jar' to classloader
1708 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/fontbox-1.8.1.jar' to classloader
1709 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/icu4j-49.1.jar' to classloader
1709 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar' to classloader
1709 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/vorbis-java-core-0.1.jar' to classloader
1709 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/tika-parsers-1.4.jar' to classloader
1709 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar' to classloader
1709 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar' to classloader
1709 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar' to classloader
1710 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/jdom-1.0.jar' to classloader
1710 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/jempbox-1.8.1.jar' to classloader
1710 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/xz-1.0.jar' to classloader
1710 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/extraction/lib/rome-0.9.jar' to classloader
1711 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/dist/solr-cell-4.6.0.jar' to classloader
1712 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/mahout-math-0.6.jar' to classloader
1712 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/hppc-0.5.2.jar' to classloader
1712 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/attributes-binder-1.2.0.jar' to classloader
1712 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/simple-xml-2.7.jar' to classloader
1713 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/carrot2-mini-3.8.0.jar' to classloader
1713 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.4.jar' to classloader
1713 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/mahout-collections-1.0.jar' to classloader
1713 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/clustering/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.7.4.jar' to classloader
1714 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/dist/solr-clustering-4.6.0.jar' to classloader
1714 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/langid/lib/jsonic-1.2.7.jar' to classloader
1714 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/langid/lib/langdetect-1.1-20120112.jar' to classloader
1715 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/dist/solr-langid-4.6.0.jar' to classloader
1716 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/velocity/lib/velocity-tools-2.0.jar' to classloader
1716 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/velocity/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar' to classloader
1716 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/velocity/lib/velocity-1.7.jar' to classloader
1716 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/contrib/velocity/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar' to classloader
1717 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/dist/solr-velocity-4.6.0.jar' to classloader
1886 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexConfig  – IndexWriter infoStream solr logging is enabled
1891 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig  – Using Lucene MatchVersion: LUCENE_46
2018 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.Config  – Loaded SolrConfig: solrconfig.xml
2026 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  – Reading Solr Schema from schema.xml
2101 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  – [collection1] Schema name=example
2616 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  – unique key field: id
2688 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.FileExchangeRateProvider  – Reloading exchange rates from file currency.xml
2695 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.FileExchangeRateProvider  – Reloading exchange rates from file currency.xml
2810 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory
2818 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] Opening new SolrCore at /root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/, dataDir=/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/data/
2820 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.JmxMonitoredMap  – No JMX servers found, not exposing Solr information with JMX.
2826 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] Added SolrEventListener for newSearcher: org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener{queries=[]}
2827 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] Added SolrEventListener for firstSearcher: org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener{queries=[{q=static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml}]}
2839 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory  – return new directory for /root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/data
2839 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – New index directory detected: old=null new=/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/data/index/
2839 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory  – return new directory for /root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/data/index
2849 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – created json: solr.JSONResponseWriter
2849 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – adding lazy queryResponseWriter: solr.VelocityResponseWriter
2850 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – created velocity: solr.VelocityResponseWriter
2853 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – created xslt: solr.XSLTResponseWriter
2853 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.response.XSLTResponseWriter  – xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=5
2930 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – no updateRequestProcessorChain defined as default, creating implicit default
2938 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /select: solr.SearchHandler
2938 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /query: solr.SearchHandler
2940 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /get: solr.RealTimeGetHandler
2940 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /browse: solr.SearchHandler
2943 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /update: solr.UpdateRequestHandler
2943 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /update/json: solr.UpdateRequestHandler
2943 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /update/csv: solr.UpdateRequestHandler
2943 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler
2944 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /update/extract: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler
2944 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler
2944 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /analysis/field: solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler
2944 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler
2944 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /analysis/document: solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler
2946 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /admin/: solr.admin.AdminHandlers
2948 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /admin/ping: solr.PingRequestHandler
2950 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /debug/dump: solr.DumpRequestHandler
2957 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /replication: solr.ReplicationHandler
2957 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
2958 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /spell: solr.SearchHandler
2958 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
2958 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /tvrh: solr.SearchHandler
2958 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: org.apache.solr.handler.js.JavaScriptRequestHandler
2958 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /js: org.apache.solr.handler.js.JavaScriptRequestHandler
2958 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
2958 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /terms: solr.SearchHandler
2958 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
2959 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  – created /elevate: solr.SearchHandler
2972 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader  – xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=60
2974 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader  – xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=60
2974 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader  – xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=60
2998 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – Hard AutoCommit: if uncommited for 15000ms; 
2998 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – Soft AutoCommit: disabled
3031 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – SolrDeletionPolicy.onInit: commits: num=1
    commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@18311fc; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_2q,generation=98}
3032 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – newest commit generation = 98
3054 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher  – Opening Searcher@1d10729 main
3058 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  – Initializing spell checkers
3064 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.spelling.DirectSolrSpellChecker  – init: {name=default,field=text,classname=solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker,distanceMeasure=internal,accuracy=0.5,maxEdits=2,minPrefix=1,maxInspections=5,minQueryLength=4,maxQueryFrequency=0.01}
3074 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  – No queryConverter defined, using default converter
3076 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent  – Loading QueryElevation from: /root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/conf/elevate.xml
3112 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler  – Commits will be reserved for  10000
3112 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@1d10729 main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_2q:204:nrt _1y(4.6):C28)}
3122 [coreLoadExecutor-3-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – registering core: collection1
3124 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – user.dir=/root/Desktop/inchoo/solr-4.6.0/example
3124 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
3161 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector  – Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
3165 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=null path=null params={event=firstSearcher&q=static+firstSearcher+warming+in+solrconfig.xml&distrib=false} hits=0 status=0 QTime=52 
3166 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – QuerySenderListener done.
3166 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  – Loading spell index for spellchecker: default
3166 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  – Loading spell index for spellchecker: wordbreak
3167 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] Registered new searcher Searcher@1d10729 main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_2q:204:nrt _1y(4.6):C28)}
```

**This is the solr log when i'm searching with a word 'IPhone'...**

```
61966 [qtp23254862-17] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/select params={fl=product_id,score&start=0&q=iphone&json.nl=map&wt=json&fq=store_id:1&rows=100} hits=28 status=0 QTime=13
```

Any thing wrong i did here...

I hope its working fine...

How do i know that whether Solr Search is working or not...

Thanks.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query to Solr was

```
fl=product_id,score&start=0&q=iphone&json.nl=map&wt=json&fq=store_id:1&rows=100
```

which means, Magento told Solr to search for products of a specific store (`fq=store_id:1` ) matching the word "iphone" (`q=iphone`) and to return the product_id and score (`fl=product_id,score`) of the found products in JSON (`wt=json`) object notation (`json.nl=map`), but a maximum of 100 hits (`rows=100`), starting with the first match (`start=0`).

According to

```
hits=28 status=0 QTime=13
```

the request was successful (`status=0`) and Solr needed 13 milliseconds (`QTime=13`) to execute the search and prepare the 28 found matches (`hits=28`) for the response.

So yes, this pretty much looks like a "working" query.